# How to extract full body content of a Bounced back email?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

[image]

The above screenshot is the sample of the Bounced Back Mail received.

I'm using the following code to extract the Body of the mail.

```
function test() 
{
  var BouncedEmails = GmailApp.search("label:test The following message was undeliverable ");

  for( var i=0;i<BouncedEmails.length;i++)
  {
    var Gmessage = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(BouncedEmails[i]);

    for(var j=0;j<Gmessage.length;j++)
    {
      var body = Gmessage[j].getPlainBody();
      Logger.log(body);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I am doing this, I got the following output.

[image]
As you can see the last part of the Body is missing, that is :

[image]

I also tried using :

```
var body = Gmessage[j].getBody();
```

instead of "GetPlainBody()" but the output was still the same.

On using :

```
 var body = Gmessage[j].getRawContent();
```

I got this as output for the missing part, which seems to me as some sort of encoding.
[image]

So my question is, how do i extract the full content of the Bounced Back Mail?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question.

This has worked for me and will pretty much work for anyone on our planet.

```
function test()
{
  var BouncedEmails = GmailApp.search("label:test The following message was undeliverable ");

  for( var i=0;i<BouncedEmails.length;i++)
  {
    var threadId = BouncedEmails[i].getId();

    var id = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var body = Gmail.Users.Threads.get(id, threadId, {format : 'full'});

    var messages = body.messages;

    var payLoad = messages[0].payload.parts[2];

    var string = JSON.stringify(payLoad);
    Logger.log(string);
  }
}
```

The solutions provided by @AmitAgarwal and @ShyamKansagra would also work for some cases, but which solution to use depends on what is your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Logger.log as it truncates the output after a certain number of lines. Log the output in a spreadsheet and you'll see that the full body is extracted with getPlainBody() or getBody().

I recently published a Google Script to get all [bounced emails in Gmail](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-bounced-email-report/29209/) and logs them to a Google sheet. It is open so can build upon that script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried logging the output in a spreadsheet before posting the question here. The output still comes the same.

Comment: I went through your published script, good job there. But that part i was able to do myself, there is an **additional task** that I'm trying to achieve which is to **extract the Subject of the original mail that was not delivered** (or that was bounced back).

Answer (score 0):

I also tried using `getBody()`, `getPlainBody()` and `getRawContent()` methods on bounced back emails. I noticed that these methods didn't give entire body of the email i.e. the part with technical details was skipped entirely in the logs.

So, I used this following code(all credits to @Amit Agarwal), which I found in the link which Amit has shared in his answer and it gave me entire body of bounced back email.

Here is the code:

```
var t = "in:anywhere from:(mailer-daemon@google.com OR mailer-daemon@googlemail.com)";
GmailApp.search(t,0,500).forEach(function(t)
                                          {
                                            t.getMessages().forEach(function(r)
                                                                    {
                                                                      if(r.getFrom().indexOf("mailer-daemon")!==-1)
                                                                      {
                                                                        var i=r.getPlainBody();
                                                                        Logger.log(i);
                                                                      }
                                                                    }
                                                                    )
                                          }

)
```

It worked for me and gave the entire content in the logs itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this for my case and the results unfortunately are disappointing. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: You are welcome. Try changing the bounceback email format on server side if you can. Also,  try to recreate the issue and check whether it is behaving the same or it behaves like that only in case of the email that you checked.

Comment: @ShyamKansagra answer worked for me. Is the subject still being encoded? Can you post the log that you get when you his code above?

Comment: @utphx didn't get what you mean by 'Is the subject still being encoded'. By the way, if I use simple `getPlainBody()`, I'm getting the body of actual email which got bounced back and not the body of bounced back email. But after using the code above, I got entire body of **bounced back email**.

Comment: @utphx Ok got it. Nope the subject did not get encoded in my case. It is showing as it is.