# How to extract full body content of email?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am new to app script and i have very little idea about the GmailApp of google app script.

I am trying to extract the body of the email that i receive and then record it in a spreadsheet along with other details associated with the mail, like subject, from Id, time etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Generally you should ask a question where in you've already tried something on your own and based on that everyone here would try and help you. I suggest you go through the documentation next time before asking any questions.

Comment: Also, try search for similar questions that have already been catered to here in order to avoid duplicating questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered:

[How to extract full body content of a Bounced back email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283545/how-to-extract-full-body-content-of-a-bounced-back-email/41344745#41344745)

Go through the above link. For further assistance make sure you show us what you've tried till now.